# Codecov coverage differs from local coverage due to renamed test

Tags: github-actions, code-coverage, codecov

I renamed and added a new test in my test suite. Following these changes, the coverage from codecov is different from the coverage I get locally.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71922850/codecov-displays-different-result-compared-to-local-results), I read the [following information](https://docs.codecov.com/docs/unexpected-coverage-changes) which proposes how to find the cause of the issue. In this case, I'm pretty sure the cause is the changing test names. What I don't understand is how to go from understanding the cause to finding a solution to the issue, i.e. getting codecov to run based on the new test names.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.